IAR how to get the value of environment args
I would like to know what is the easiest way to get the value from the IAR's environment args such as $TOOLKIT_DIR$ or $PROJ_DIR$.
I know what method uses Windows for it's environment variables, but I guess that those one that are used for IAR are not being exported.
Thanks in advance

Are you sure this is an electrical engineering question? Doesn't IAR have support people or forums for questions how to use their sotware, if this information is not in a manual?

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Electrical Engineering.

If you wanted to ask that question elsewhere, please add more details what you wanted to do with those args and when.

Sorry for that @Justme and forgive me my life for it. I forgot that IAR was an IDE for developing fruits and vegetables.

I'm not a user of IAR, but looking at the IDE Project Management
and Building Guide for Arm Limited’s Arm® Cores $TOOLKIT_DIR$ and $PROJ_DIR$ are described as Argument variables.
The Build actions and Argument variables technical note contains:

Argument variables are not Environment Variables, in other words, Argument variables are not automatically available for evaluation inside scripts.

Therefore, as far as I can tell the IAR build tool doesn't support exporting the value of Argument variables for use by 3rd party scripts or tools.
